# Laravel Model without a Database?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm developing a system in which i have different roles for accesing. The role is present in the Users table as an integer value.

I've created a model called roles and in this model i dont need a database connection or a table. I did set some constant values representing roles matching the role field in the user table.

So what's the problem ? It seems that i can't have relations with the roles model if this   hasn't a table associated in the database.

This is my roles model:

```
class Roles extends Model {

    const ROL_ADMINISTRADOR = 1;
    const ROL_DIRECTOR = 2;
    const ROL_PROFESOR = 3;
    const ROL_RECOPILADOR = 4;

    private $rol_id;
    private $roles = [
        self::ROL_ADMINISTRADOR => 'Administrador',
        self::ROL_DIRECTOR => 'Director',
        self::ROL_PROFESOR => 'Profesor',
        self::ROL_RECOPILADOR => 'Recopilador'
    ];

    /**
     * RELACIONES
     */
    public function _usuarios() {
        return $this->hasMany(Usuarios::class, "rol", "rol_id");
    }

    /**
     * FORMATEADORES
     */

    /**
     * FUNCIONES
     */

    public function nombre() {
        return $this->roles[$this->rol_id];
    }

}
```

This is my users model

```
class Usuarios extends Authenticatable {

    use Notifiable;

    const STATUS_ACTIVO = 1;
    const STATUS_INACTIVO = 0;

    protected $table = 'usuarios';
    protected $primaryKey = 'usuario_id';

    /*
     * RELACIONES
     */

    public function _rol() {
         return $this->hasOne(Roles::class, 'rol', 'rol_id');
    }

    public function _perfil() {
        return $this->hasOne(Perfiles::class, "usuario", "usuario_id");
    }

    /*
     * FORMATEADORES
     */
}
```

But i got this error

```
Base table or view not found: 1146
```

When i try to do this

```
<?= Auth::user()->_rol->nombre()  ?>
```

=========================================================================

I think i've found the solution.

I did the following changes:

1.- in the roles model I did add the constructor method and customized it

```
public function __construct($rol) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->rol_id = $rol;    
}
```

2.- In the users model change the method to this

```
public function _rol() {
        return new Roles($this->usuario_id);
    }
```

There is a thing here: if the method is called like this '_rol' the model will think is about a relation and will required a relation response so is neccesary to call it this way '_rol()' (with the parenthesis)

```
<?= Auth::user()->_rol()->nombre() ?>
```

Comment: did you solve it?? or you need any help

Comment: Yes. Problem Solved

Answer (score 0):

You only need the Role model if you have another table to store the roles.
If you, instead, have the role represented as a field in the users table, you can access it just doing:

```
$role = $user->role;
```

Comment: But there are a lot of roles, and also i want to query the users from the role model.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use https://github.com/artesaos/defender to manage roles and permitions.